# Install Printer Without Connecting to the Internet?

Tags: internet, printing, live-cd

I have a Brother Hl-2230 printer which I am able to install using the Hl-2170W driver that is pre-included with Ubuntu. Note I am running Ubuntu off of a 'liveCD' USB.

If I am not connected to the internet and try to install the 2170W it successfully installs but the printer will not print.

If I am connected to the internet while installing the 2170W driver it works entirely.

Does anyone know why this is happening, and if I can install the driver without connecting to the internet?

Comment: Perhaps they are dependencies (packages) that have to be downloaded to get the print to work.